# separate long vectors into individual numbers in a data frame

Tags: r

[image: The dataframe looks like this]

I have a data frame of 1000 vectors which are all similar to this 001010.... etc.

I'm trying to create a data frame where each vector is a column and each row is a single number from the vector.

So my first vector would be:

```
vector1
0
0
1
0
1
0
...
```

This is what I've tried so far but I haven't gotten it working yet.

```
text <- data_frame()
for (i in 1:length(text_vector_data)){
    for (digit in i){
        text_df <- rbind(digit, text)}
}
```

The output of str(text_vector_data) is

```
tibble [2,225 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ wordcountvec: chr [1:2225] "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,"| __truncated__ "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,"| __truncated__ "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,"| __truncated__ "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,"| __truncated__ ...
```

Comment: Hi Matt, when you say "I have a data frame of 1000 vectors", what do you mean exactly? Could you [edit] your question with the output of `str(text_vector_data)`?

Comment: Furthermore, the `for (i in 1:length(....))` argument can’t be passed to `for(digit in i...)` because `i` will be a number. You’ll have to specify a row such as `for( digit in vector[i]...)` for example.

Comment: Are they all the same number of digits?  Also, are they all 1s and 0s?

Comment: No, They can be any Natural Number. However, they are mostly 0's and 1's

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `strsplit` like below

```
> data.frame(setNames(strsplit(v, ""), paste0("V", seq_along(v))))
  V1 V2 V3
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0
3  1  1  0
4  0  1  1
5  1  0  0
6  0  0  1
```

**Dummy Data**

```
v <- c("001010", "101100", "000101")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `read.fwf`

```
read.fwf(textConnection(v), widths = rep(1, nchar(v[1])))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#1  0  0  1  0  1  0
#2  1  0  1  1  0  0
#3  0  0  0  1  0  1
```

and to return the transpose

```
as.data.frame(t(read.fwf(textConnection(v), widths = rep(1, nchar(v[1])))))
```

#### data

```
v <- c("001010", "101100", "000101")
```