# Separate long numbers into individual components in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with several hundred vectors that look like this

[image]

To analyze them I must split the columns so that the number is separated into its individual components in the rows beneath.

```
V1
0
0
0
0
0
0
...
```

I've tried using this code and tweaking it but I can't get it to work. There are 2225 columns and the vectors are not all the same size.

```
text_data <- read_excel("./data/wordcount_vectors.xlsx")
text_vector_data <- text_data %>% select(wordcountvec)
```

```
wordvec_list <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(text_vector_data)){
  text_vector_data[i,] <- removePunctuation(as.character(text_vector_data[i,]))
  x <- as.list(text_vector_data[i,])
  wordvec_list <- c(wordvec_list, x)
}

wordvec_df <- as.data.frame(wordvec_list)
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2225, nrow = 1106))
for (i in 1:ncol(text_vector_data)){ #Change range depending on size of c
  c <- as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(wordvec_df[i]), "")[[1]])
  dd[i] <- c[[i]]
}
word_vec_df <- Filter(function(x)!all(is.na(x)), dd)
row.names(word_vec_df)<- NULL ; colnames(word_vec_df)<- NULL
word_vec_df <- t(word_vec_df)
```

here's some toy data to try

```
v1 <- (100011000)
v2 <- (10102100)
v3 <- (1120210011)

wordcount_df <- data_frame(v1,v2,v3)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data that we can use, neither an image (I'm not spending time scraping it) nor a reference to a file we don't have. It's generally preferred to keep questions self-contained and reproducible; a popular method is to build sample data programmatically (e.g., with `data.frame(...)`) or [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(head(x,10))` (where 10 is relative to the point you're trying to make ... big enough to present enough variability, small enough to not be more data than is necessary).

Comment: That looks very similar to your previous question [separate long vectors into individual numbers in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534310/separate-long-vectors-into-individual-numbers-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: Sorry, I've added some sample data to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to read your data as character not numeric because otherwise the leading zeros will be lost:

```
text_data <- read_excel("./data/wordcount_vectors.xlsx", col_types="text")
```

Your example does not include spaces between the 1's and 0's but your picture does. Using your provided data:

```
wordcount_dfc <- as.character(wordcount_df)
wordcount_dfc
# [1] "100011000"  "10102100"   "1120210011"
wordcount_lst <- strsplit(wordcount_dfc, "")    # Use " " if the values are separated by spaces
wordcount_lst <-sapply(wordcount_lst, as.integer)
wordcount_lst
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 0 1 0 2 1 0 0
#
# [[3]]
#  [1] 1 1 2 0 2 1 0 0 1 1
sapply(wordcount_lst, length)
# [1]  9  8 10
```

You cannot just bind the columns together because they are of different lengths. The simplest approach would be to use `wordcount_lst` directly, but if you need to make a data frame, you need to add NAs to pad out short vectors:

```
size <- max(sapply(wordcount_lst, length))
wordcount_df <- data.frame(sapply(wordcount_lst, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, size - length(x)))))
wordcount_df
#    X1 X2 X3
# 1   1  1  1
# 2   0  0  1
# 3   0  1  2
# 4   0  0  0
# 5   1  2  2
# 6   1  1  1
# 7   0  0  0
# 8   0  0  0
# 9   0 NA  1
# 10 NA NA  1
```